# in sql rows to columns conversion for one person having 2 or more emails in rows want output in single column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

hey guys I have a small issue in SQL I have a table shown below

each name has at least 2 emails shown in the table I want an output in which the name is in one row and all emails side by side
if any solution help out

Table

```
col1         |       col2
__________________________
abhi         | xyz@email
abhi         | abc@email
abhi         | rst@email
ragu         | str@email
ragu         | pqr@email
```

expected output:

```
col1         |     col2
abhi         |     xyz@email,abc@email,rst@email
ragu         |     str@email,pqr@email
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466):

```
select col1, listagg(col2, ',') within group (order by col2)
from t
group by col1;
```